# expected a ';' - I've copied this code from a learning resource and it doesn't work

Tags: c++, syntax

I'm having trouble with the syntax of my prototyping and implementation of function. The first bracket `{` right below my function's implementation keeps throwing an error saying:

> expected a ';'

I am literally copying and pasting this code from this learning [resource here](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/yAqpX9L8/) because I assumed they would have no errors.  Is this something super simple that I am missing?  I have tried rebuilding, taking a break and coming back, starting a brand new project and copying/pasting it again from the web page. Adding a semicolon just breaks the function in other ways as expected.  I'm using VS 2015.

```
int main() {

    double someFunction(double, int);

    double someFunction(double x, int y)
    {  
        return x * y;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try moving the function declaration and definition outside the `main()` function.

Comment: You can't have another function *inside* `main`. Just move it outside.

Comment: Look more closely at the original: It does **not** declare `someFunction()` inside main.

Comment: I see that now, I was taking it as a simple example and not remember it was part of the whole and the relationship to main() ... thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
//Prototype  
double someFunction(double, int);

//Main 
int main() {
    //calling your function
    someFunction(0.5,2);

    return 0; 
}

//Function definition
double someFunction(double x, int y)
{  
    return x * y;
}
```

Should be like this.

Comment: Because I'm lazy and like less maintenance, I'd define `someFunction` ahead of `main` and discard the forward declaration. Sucks when the prototype is changed to `double someFunction(double, long);` and no longer matches the function. You get this weird "undefined reference to..." error which looks like BS because the function's like *right there...*